# ReCaptcha Reload Upon the Selection of the Button

Tags: javascript, reload

We are a small nonprofit organization and desperately need assistance as follows:

We have an issue; click the submit button, and the ReCaptcha forces the frame to reload. In that interval, the comment section sort of goes down a layer.

Question: How does our developer remove the blue reCAPTCHA row upon selecting the comments button?

See the screenshot images below for details.

Note: The issue did not exist without the IFrame Player API.

Hal

Screenshot image of the Error Message below:

[image: Screenshot image Error Message]

GitHub Gist link to Front-End Browser code, [here](https://gist.github.com/CforED/62c7013e51dc85f49180c3308e742d26).

Front-End Browser Code

```
<script src="https://gist.github.com/CforED/62c7013e51dc85f49180c3308e742d26.js"></script>
```

IFrame Player API Script

```
<script>
    // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
    var tag = document.createElement('script');

    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
    //    after the API code downloads.
    var player;
    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
            
            videoId: 'WLkkzqzo4p0',
            playerVars: { 'autoplay': 1, 'playsinline': 1,'loop': 1, 'controls': 0, 'playlist': 'WLkkzqzo4p0'},
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady
            }
        });
    }

    // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.mute();
        event.target.playVideo();
    }
```

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(e,t,o,n,p,r,i){e.visitorGlobalObjectAlias=n;e[e.visitorGlobalObjectAlias]=e[e.visitorGlobalObjectAlias]||function(){(e[e.visitorGlobalObjectAlias].q=e[e.visitorGlobalObjectAlias].q||[]).push(arguments)};e[e.visitorGlobalObjectAlias].l=(new Date).getTime();r=t.createElement("script");r.src=o;r.async=true;i=t.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];i.parentNode.insertBefore(r,i)})(window,document,"https://diffuser-cdn.app-us1.com/diffuser/diffuser.js","vgo");
vgo('setAccount', '224274263');
vgo('setTrackByDefault', true);

vgo('process');
```

[image: Screenshot Image wo/ Error Mesage]
[image: Screenshot Image with Error Message]